# How to implement a variable-length heterogeneous sequence of structs

Tags: c, data-structures

There's 2 structs of different sizes:

```
struct A{
    int x, y, z;
};

struct B{
    float x, y;
};
```

At runtime, the program generates a sequence of instances of these two structs.

A hand-written example could look like:

```
Struct A a0 = { ... };
Struct A a1 = { ... };
Struct B b0 = { ... };
Struct A a2 = { ... };
Struct B b1 = { ... };
Struct B b2 = { ... };
```

So, in this case, the "sequence" is `a0, a1, b0, a2, b1, b2`.

**I'd like to "place" this sequence into some data structure**. (The length of the full sequence is only known at runtime, as well as the order of appearance of each instance of `struct A` and `struct B`.)

What's the simplest way to do this?

In Python, for instance, I'd do something like:

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z

Class B:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

# Manual example
a0 = A(...)
a1 = A(...)
b0 = B(...)
a2 = A(...)
b1 = B(...)
b2 = B(...)

my_list = []

# The list gets updated as the program runs
my_list.append(a0)
my_list.append(a1)
my_list.append(b0)
my_list.append(a2)
my_list.append(b1)
my_list.append(b2)
# etc., etc.
```

How can I do the equivalent in C?

Comment: wraper struct and union with A and B.

Comment: Too broad/opinionated. However, you should think about what it implies that the standard Python implementation is written in C.

Comment: Not too broad, IMO, but underspecified:  array has an O(1) lookup time.  This can be achieved in the OP case by using additional space (either through a union or via an index).  Or you can only the space required by the structs and have an O(n) lookup.  Can you describe the requirement in speed/space terms?

Comment: So basically you want a variable length array that can handle multiple types?

Comment: The list in python holds references, you know.. I'd say it's pretty homogeneous

Comment: @danh The requirements are: No random access. No insertions (only "appends" at the end). No deletions. Only sequential reads. Traversal should be O(n). Space should be O(n).

Comment: The difference with python is the difference between statically and dynamically typed languages. You can't do in C in such a flexible way as in python, but flexibility comes with a cost and also drawbacks. You can find neverending debates about this all around the internet.

Comment: @Juan That's not strictly true. You can implement in C any sort of abstraction you want (it may be hard, however). You can even implement dynamic typing using C. Python is implemented in C. Anything you can do in Python, you can do using C. It just may take a lot of work, and your abstraction may be heavyweight (like Python).

Comment: Totally agree, you can do the same things, like with any touring-complete language. I personally try to take profit of language features and live with the drawbacks. But if you do want an heterogeneous list, I'd personally choose koper89 solution or a variant of it. For example, if space efficiency is critical, you can directly use the unions without the enum and then use a bit set to keep track of the type of element.

Comment: @Juan Yup, I'm gonna go with the unions solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using union here, to wrap both structs in one:

```
 union Data {
      struct A A;
      struct B B;
 };
```

Additionally you could use enum or any other variable type to specify what you store in this union currently:

```
 enum DataType {
      TYPE_A = 0,
      TYPE_B
 };
```

And finally you wrap both of them in a struct:

```
 struct DataHolder {
      union Data Data;
      enum DataType DataType;
 };
```

Then to make it as you wanted as list you can use pointer to DataHolder or use it as array and put your list inside. Append could be using dynamic reallocation (realloc). But function to append it would need to have access to, how many items are currently inside of your list, and type of data you wish to add to your list.

Comment: My only concern with this is that _every_ instance of `DataHolder` will be as large as the largest of `A` and `B` (is this correct??). Assume `A` is much larger than `B`. Then a sequence of `DataHolder` instances comprising mostly "instances" of `B` will be very wasteful in terms of space. This solution is very convenient, though. I can, as you say, use an array of `DataHolder` objects to do precisely what I want.

Comment: Yes, you're right that every DataHolder will be "largest" possible part of union. But you could as well make it differently i.e. instead of union put in DataHolder void * and point to any struct.
 struct DataHolder {
      void *Data;
      enum DataType DataType;
 }; This way you would safe space, but you would have to allocate DataHolder and Data inside separately and you would have to cast it to according strctures in code based on DataType. Like in answer below me.

Answer (score 1):

Use of pointers makes a heterogeneous array possible.

```
typedef struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}*PA;

typedef struct B {
    float x;
    float y;
}*PB;

void main() {
    void * Instance[2];
    A a;
    B b;

    Instance[0] = &a;
    Instance[1] = &b;

    ((PA)(Instance[0]))->x = 2;
}
```

But now you can have any type which raises the question of just how are you supposed to know what type to expect at any given index? If you decide to just start cataloging types which are allowable then why not just use a union?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but your example shows it store the classes but how further program know how to use elements of the list?

Comment: Each struct contains a header that specifies the type! Also: why not use a union? I don't know